# Change Android App Icon and App Name programmatically without adding them in bundle source code?

Tags: android, kotlin, icons, appicon

I am building an android application in android studio. I want to change the application launcher icon and name after the application gets installed.

Here comes the challenging part the icon and name information will be coming from webServer. So we can't use 'activity-alias' and we can't add that icon with the bundle source code.

Can't add an application shortcut too. Want to change the main app laucher icon and it's name

Comment: Make shortcuts instead: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts

Comment: I don't want the app shortcuts icon as it's not supported on all devices.

Comment: "Open to suggestion" It seems you are not.

Comment: @Blundell Even I am exploring more if got something good will be adding that to the answer. have edited question please don't mind